# Best way to crimping the outer tabs of a Crimp Terminal Contact

Tags: crimp

I'm trying to find the best way to crimp the [JST VH series crimp terminal contact](https://benl.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-connector-contacts/7620702)

[image]

I'm using my Knippex tool to perform the crimp

[image]
[image]

Now I always get good results with the inner tabs, but the outer tabs that need to grip with the insulation is never properly crimped.

[image]

I always need to do perform "a final non-standard step" using my tool to crimp the outer tabs.

[image]

Only then am I able to insert the contact in the housing. (otherwise the outer tabs are too wide in order for them to fit into the housing.

[image]

This "final non-standard step" for me is error-prone, as I'm sometimes not able to crimp the outer tabs properly, and need multiple times before I can get it to fit the housing.

Given that there are many different terminal contacts, with different inner / outer tabs, I assume there is no 1 universal tool to handle them all.

What would be the best way to deal with this ?

Comment: The Molex tool, [63811-1000](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0638111000/WM9999-ND/243789), includes the insulation crimper, as well. It is that kind of tool to look for. Not necessarily the one I linked. But a tool that includes both crimping jaws in a single tool.

Comment: I trim the insulation crimp wings prior to crimping. I cut off roughly 1/3 of the length. I am sure the proper tool does a good job without trimming. However this is with JST crimps that are a bit smaller.

Comment: That looks like a generic quick-disconnect crimper, not the specialised crimper for those terminals.  Sometimes I use ordinary thin nose pliers to finish off crimps when I don't have the right crimp tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not getting good crimps is simply because you are using the wrong tool. There is no universal tool that is going to work with every type of crimp contact that you can purchase in the market place.

Most of the reputable manufacturers of crimp terminals will also sell a hand tool designed specifically for a certain series of crimp contacts. The best of these tools are rather expensive and it is not uncommon for them to cost into the several 100 USD. But if you want to make repeatedly reliable crimps it is essential to have the proper tool.

From a design engineer viewpoint when it is necessary to build prototypes from time to time it can be a useful strategy select one or two connector lines that you can use for the greater percentage of your connection needs and then purchase the appropriate tools for those lines.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. AFAIK this Knipex 97 52 34 isn't related to any particular crimp terminal. It only specifies 0.1 tot 2.5 mm² and 27-13 AWG. For what kind of crimp terminals is this tool appropriate ?

Comment: @ddewaele - There is no way I can provide information on that crimper. There are tons of "general purpose" crimpers sold in the market place. These range from total crap to reasonable decent quality. As to whether any of these are suitable for any specific style/design/size of crimp terminal is really a trial and error exercise. You tried that crimper and got unsatisfactory results - thus wrong tool for the job. The real that that you need to ask is: "I have this crimp terminal and I need to find the crimp tool recommended by the manufacturer".